# SQL server bulk copy (bcp) for linux (centos)

Tags: sql-server, linux, centos, data-import

Does [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org) support SQL Server 2008 R2? Is there any other good tool to import data from SQL server to my centos machine?

Answer (score 2):

It **does** support it, however there may be some specific datatypes and features that are problematic. Please see this link:

http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#Does.FreeTDS.support.my.server

and this link

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

You can use [jbcp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbcp/), and it's pretty similar to freebcp from FreeTDS. It's a cleanroom implementation of the TDS protocol in Java, including the BCP part of it.

Note that **export** isn't supported by jbcp, but AFAIK, it is supported by freebcp. This is a bit OT to your question though.

You can also use SSIS from SQL server itself (over SMB share, etc), but there isn't a lot of detail in your question, so I can't be sure as to how the data is stored on the Linux box and how accessible the Linux box is from SQL machine.